# auth0 parseHash can't create property '__enableIdPInitiatedLogin' on hash string

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm trying to upgrade my React web app from auth0-js 9.6.1 to 9.7.3. After installing the new library, my Slack login flow no longer works, it appears to be breaking in the callback.

```
TypeError: Cannot create property '__enableIdPInitiatedLogin' on string '#access_token={token string}&token_type=Bearer&state={state string}'
```

My `parseHash` call is:

```
this.auth0.parseHash(hash, (err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.idToken) {
    AuthService.setToken(authResult.idToken); // JWT returned from Auth0;

    // Redirect user to content.
    const returnUrl = localStorage.getItem(Variables.RETURN_URL_KEY);
    localStorage.removeItem(Variables.RETURN_URL_KEY);
    returnUrl
        ? window.location.replace(returnUrl)
        : window.location.replace("/");
  } else if (err) {
    console.log("Error with auth callback", err);
    window.location.replace("https://foo.com"); // If auth fails, send user to home page.
  }
}
```

This works fine in 9.6.1, but fails in 9.7.x and I can't find anything about any breaking changes that would cause it to start failing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue as you so I opened a [ticket on the Auth0.js library github page.](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/823)

This is the response I got from the developers:

> It was working by accident then (also, the string is being ignored in your case), considering that we expect the first parameter to either be an object or a callback function.
>
> All of our docs mention that:
>
> https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js#api
>
> https://auth0.github.io/auth0.js/global.html#parseHash
>
> https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9#extract-the-authresult-and-get-user-info
>
> In your case, **the simplest fix is to just remove the first parameter and keep only the callback**. window.location.hash is already used when there's no options object.

(emphasis on the fix mine)

I tested 9.7.3 with `this.auth.auth0.parseHash((err, result) => ...` and it worked like a charm.

I hope this'll help!